# Is there a way to dynamically update ratings

Tags: list, updatelistitems

For Ratings there are two fields in share point.

Rating (0-5)
Number of Ratings

Is there a way to dynamically update these values by code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can update these values by code using `SocialRatingManager` class in sharepoint 2013.
For more details check the below link

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Programmatically-Manage-List-Items-Rating-with-Social-Rating-Manager-in-SharePoint-2013

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Garima for the reply...

I used this solution 
http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2013/06/13/setting-page-ratings-using-sharepoint-client-object-model/

Following is the code for reference....

```
var listId = "LIST ID";
var itemId = "ID OF ASSET TO BE RATED";
var rating = RATING IN NUMERIC; //This can be from 1 to 5

EnsureScriptFunc(scriptbase + 'reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation', function() {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        rating = Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(ctx, listId, itemId , rating);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(done, fail);
    });

function done() {
 alert("Done");
}

function fail() {
 alert("Failed");
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about how you solved the issue? This link can break!

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to 

provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general 

guidelines.